# backports/lzma/_lzmamodule.c:115:18: fatal error: lzma.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, docker

I'm trying to install docker-registry. I got stuck after this:

```
$ apt-get install python-pip python-dev
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
[...]
backports/lzma/_lzmamodule.c:115:18: fatal error: lzma.h: No such file or directory
```

The docker-registry I downloaded is v0.6.7

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
$ apt-get install -y liblzma-dev
```

Comment: Anyone know the Cantos-7 name for this package?

Answer (score 19):

On Centos the package is

```
yum install -y xz-devel
```

Answer (score 7):

For OSX with Homebrew.

```
brew install xz
```

The formula is `xz` because `lzma` formula is deprecated, since it became a part of `xz`.

Answer (score 1):

And finally on RedHat (I tested it on RHEL 7.4)

`yum install -y xz-devel`